# Binary Search method

Tags: java, search, binary

Hi this program acts as if you are shopping in a grocery store. The only problem is that I'm having trouble getting the binary search down. It is suppose to search the array cart for the string that the person is looking for. However, its not quite working (meaning I'm not sure whats wrong). If you could just take a look and see if theres a noticeable problem, that'd be great. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class shop
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userAns,name;
        int amount;
        double price;
        ShoppingCart newCart = new ShoppingCart();

        System.out.println("Would you like to shop at Sam's Club?");
        userAns = scan.nextLine();

        if(userAns.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            while(userAns.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("Please type in the products name you would like to purchase:");
                name = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Please type in the number of products you would like to purchase");
                amount = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Please type in the amount of money it costs:");
                price = scan.nextDouble();

                newCart.addToCart(name,price,amount);

                System.out.println(newCart);

                System.out.println("Would you like to continue shopping at Sam's Club?");
                userAns = scan.next();
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to check your cart for an item?");
            String userScan = scan.next();

            if(userScan.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                binarySearch(newCart);

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Have a nice day!");

    }
}

    // **********************************************************************
    //   ShoppingCart.java
    //
    //   Represents a shopping cart as an array of items
    // **********************************************************************

    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class ShoppingCart
    {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private int itemCount;      // total number of items in the cart
private double totalPrice;  // total price of items in the cart
private int capacity;       // current cart capacity
Item[] cart;
int i = 0; 

// -----------------------------------------------------------
//  Creates an empty shopping cart with a capacity of 5 items.
// -----------------------------------------------------------
public ShoppingCart()
{
  capacity = 5;
  itemCount = 0;
  totalPrice = 0.0;
  cart = new Item[capacity];
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Adds an item to the shopping cart.
// -------------------------------------------------------
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
{
  if(i == cart.length)
  {
    increaseSize();
  }
  else
  {
  Item newItem = new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
  cart[i] = newItem;
  totalPrice = (price*quantity)+totalPrice;
  itemCount++;
  i++;
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Returns the contents of the cart together with
//  summary information.
// -------------------------------------------------------
public String toString()
{
 NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

 String contents = "\nShopping Cart\n";
 contents += "\nItem:\t\tUnit Price: \tQuantity:\t\tTotal:\n";

 for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
 contents += cart[i].toString() + "\n";

 contents += "\nTotal Price: " + fmt.format(totalPrice);
 contents += "\n";

 return contents;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------
//  Increases the capacity of the shopping cart by 3
// ---------------------------------------------------------
private void increaseSize()
{
  Item[] temp = new Item[cart.length+3];
  for(int item=0; item < cart.length; item++)
  {
    temp[item] = cart[item];
  }
  cart = temp;
}

public void binarySearch()
{
  System.out.println("Type in the object you would like to search for: ");
  String object = scan.next();
  int high = cart.length-1;
  int low = 0;
  int middle = (low+high)/2;

  while(!(cart[middle].getName().equals(object)) && low<=high)
  {
    if((cart[middle].getName()).compareTo(object) > 0)
      if(cart[middle].getName().equals(object))
      high = middle-1;

      else
        low = middle+1;

      middle = (low+high)/2;
  }
    if(cart[middle].getName().equals(object))
      System.out.println("Your item is found!");
    else
      System.out.println("Your item is not found.");


  }     
}
```

I don't think this is the problem but I will add this next one just incase:

```
// ***************************************************************
//   Item.java
//
//   Represents an item in a shopping cart.
// ***************************************************************

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item
{
private String name;
private double price;
private int quantity;


// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Create a new item with the given attributes.
// -------------------------------------------------------
public Item (String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased)
{
 name = itemName;
 price = itemPrice;
 quantity = numPurchased;
}


// -------------------------------------------------------
//   Return a string with the information about the item
// -------------------------------------------------------
public String toString()
{
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

return (name + "\t\t" + fmt.format(price) + "\t\t" + quantity + "\t\t"
+ fmt.format(price*quantity));
}

// -------------------------------------------------
//   Returns the unit price of the item
// -------------------------------------------------
public double getPrice()
{
 return price;
}

// -------------------------------------------------
//   Returns the name of the item
// -------------------------------------------------
public String getName()
{
 return name;
}

// -------------------------------------------------
//   Returns the quantity of the item
// -------------------------------------------------
public int getQuantity()
{
 return quantity;
}

}
```

Comment: Is your array sorted when your perform your binary search?

Comment: Well the array is a string array, so it should be by lexicographic order.

Comment: Your cart array is not a String array. If you want to perform a binary search on the names, your items have to be sorted by names in the array. Also I don't see a method `binarySearch(ShoppingCart sc);`, but you are calling `binarySearch(newCart);`